# Set permission set assignment expiration by a code or a script?

Tags: permission-sets, permission-set-assignment

I try to automate the tasks given by maintenance modules to be done manually, since I find it more interesting.
For Winter 23 App Builder maintenance, App Builder should create a permission set and assign it to some user.

There is an SFDX command to assign a permission set

`sfdx force:user:permset:assign -n Name -o user -u org`

however, it doesn't have a parameter to specify expiration date, so if I try to execute

`sfdx force:user:permset:assign -n ReportPermissions`, such command won't set the expiration date.

How can I assign a permission set with expiration date by a code or a script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible by combining `Apex` and `sh`.

First create a file `assignCurrentUser.apex` inside scripts/apex of your project.

```
PermissionSet ps = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE Name = 'PermName' AND NamespacePrefix = 'PrefixNamespace' LIMIT 1];
insert new PermissionSetAssignment(AssigneeId = UserInfo.getUserId(), PermissionSetId = ps.Id, ExpirationDate = Date.today() + 30);
```

and then create a file `acu.sh` in scripts folder

```
code=$(cat scripts/apex/assignCurrentUser.apex)   
code="${code/PrefixNamespace/$1}"
echo "${code/PermName/$2}" > temp.apex
sfdx force:apex:execute -f temp.apex
rm temp.apex
```

and finally execute

`./acu.sh '' ReportPermissions`